# TCPDF runs slow and consumes huge amounts of memory

Tags: php, tcpdf

TCPDF is an open source PDF generator I'm using in a web app of mine for generating reports. These reports are standard pre-made HTML tables, which TCPDF reads and converts into a PDF. Lately The reports have been running multiple pages and are taking much longer than I'd like to load.

**The problems**

- TCPDF is currently generating the PDFs at 0.48s per page.
- TCPDF uses on average 3-4 MB RAM per page during generation, often timing out the half gig php limit I have set. (512/4 = 128 = my page limit), even though the final file will be below 1MB.

**What I've tried**

- Initially I thought the long wait time may have been down to database
  calls for the required info and my php script generating the HTML, however timestamps on each page of the report, and also printing time
  stamps at the completion of database calls and HTML generation rule out that possibility.
- First thing I tried was updating TCPDF because I am running a 2010 version, this actually increased the load time by a factor of 4x!   (however the new version was more memory efficient)
- I've tried re-writing the HTML, removing all images and including all CSS in a style tag at the top (previously it was contained in each HTML tag), however this actually slowed the generation by 50%!

**Question**

1. Is there anyone whoes had a similar problem that can point out some other common edits which can improve the loading?
2. What are my alternatives from using HTML tables and TCPDF that can provide a more efficient way of generating the PDF?

Worst case scenario, I think I might have to make a separate PDF generating machine which does every report page by page, mashes them together, and Emails it when its done but that sounds naaasty.

Comment: that looks about the same as i get (per core) its an inherintly slow process creating pdf's

Comment: `<tr nobr="true">` causes significant slowdowns

Comment: going back to my notes the fastest i got was  28 pages per second (5 page pdf's) on a dedicated 8 core machine. you need to do something to use all 8 cores as php wont out of the box

Comment: Using HTML is obviously the easiest solution but PDFs aren't made with HTML, they are rendered in blocks so TCPDF has to convert your HTML code into blocks that PDF uses. `MultiCell()` produces the best performance but is definitely tricky to work with.

Comment: Have you looked into [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)?